# How to replace character with newline?

Tags: xstring

`xstring`: I want something like this `\StrSubstitute{abc,cde}{,}{\newline}`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\StrSubstitute{abc,def}{,}{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\newline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`xstring` package](//ctan.org/pkg/xstring) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/xstring) alludes to this (section **3.1.1 The commands `\fullexpandarg`, `\expandarg` and `\noexpandarg`**):

> The command `\fullexpandarg` is called by default, so all the arguments are fully expanded (an `\edef` is used) before the the macro works on them. In most of the cases, this expansion mode avoids chains of `\expandafter` and allows lighter code. Of course, the expansion of argument can be canceled to find back the usual behaviour of TeX with the commands `\noexpandarg` or `\normalexpandarg`.
>
> In the following list, [...] the arguments colored in purple will possibly be expanded, according to the expansion mode:
>
> [image]

You're placing `\newline` in `<stringB>`, which is causing the issue when trying to be expanded. Adding `\normalexpandarg` after loading `xstring` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\normalexpandarg

\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute{abc,cde}{,}{;}

\StrSubstitute{abc,cde}{,}{\newline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**A `listofitems` approach**

Limitation: the separator cannot be parsed inside a group (i.e., the comma cannot be inside the `\textbf` argument and be converted to a newline)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\subnewlines[2]{%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\parsethis{#2}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\parsethis[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\relax\else\newline\fi
    \z
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\subnewlines{,}{abc,def,a test of \textbf{big}, proportions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**A `tokcycle` approach**

This approach is *unique* in that it allows the separator inside of groups, with no loss of functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\subnewlines[2]{%
  \tokcycle
  {\ifx##1#1\addcytoks{\newline}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {#2}%
  \the\cytoks%
}
\begin{document}
\subnewlines{,}{abc,def,a test of \textbf{big,ly} proportions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `expl3` and `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % also loads expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__schneider_substitute_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \schneider_substitute:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__schneider_substitute_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__schneider_substitute_tl { #2 } { #3 }
    \l__schneider_substitute_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \substitute { +m +m +m }
  {
    \schneider_substitute:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\substitute{abc,cde}{,}{\newline}
\end{document}
```

[image]